# SQL code reduction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below SQL code is in the where clause. Is there any other way that we can write to cut short this.The below code is repeating many times. I wanted to cut short this code

```
((Business_Unit = 'A'
and ((
convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
) >= 100))
OR


(Business_Unit = 'B'
AND ((
convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
) >=100.00)
AND (text7 != 'N')
OR 

Business_Unit = 'B'
AND ((
convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
) >=100.00)
AND (text7 = 'N')
and (text4 != '')
OR Business_Unit = 'B'
AND ((
convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
) > 300.00)
AND (text7 = 'N')
and (text4 = ''))
OR
(Business_Unit = 'C'
and ((
convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
) >= 150)`enter code here`
and text1 != 'N')
```

Comment: Maybe stuff it into a function? Though there's something really wrong when you're storing monetary value in a string. Why not just use money data type in the first place?

Comment: it is working fine. There are no errors when i execute but i just wanted to do something with the repeatable code.

Comment: if you check the below code its repeating again and again. i wanted to avoid that,convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
) >= 100))

Comment: Which is why I said stuff it into function. If you insist on using free string form to store monetary values, make the whole conversion routine into a scalar function.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Lots of non-ANSI SQL there...

Comment: That isn't a complete SQL statement. Is that part of the WHERE clause? Or the select list?

Comment: This is sql statement under where clause

Comment: It might be easier to show use some sample data and the expected output based on that data. **[EDIT]** your question don't post code or additional information in comments and use [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: can we keep the whole thing in any function and use it as suggested by Martheen(
convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 ) = '-'
then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1) else
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))) end)
)

Comment: @Martheen Stuffing things in the wrong type of function will cause performance problems, just saying. A scalar function will most likely be bad, if not now, then later when the amount of data increases.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Which is why I mention in my first comment he's doing something wrong by using string as for monetary values. But he insist on it.

Comment: Thanks Martheen..@RaduGheorghiu the data is good. i am able to extract the data but the thing is i wanted that to use either function or CTE or tabular  column.. The approach im not able to figure out

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `CTE` here. The idea is to prepare the data for your where clause:

```
;with cte as 
(--your current query here without where clasuse
 --just add the following to the select list 
 convert(money, case when substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),
                                   len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),
                                   1) = '-'
                    then substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)), 1,
                                   len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)))
                                   - 1)
                    else substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)), 1,
                                   len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))))
                end) as pc
)
select * from cte
where 
    (Business_Unit = 'A' and pc >= 100) or
    (Business_Unit = 'B' and pc >= 100 and text7 != 'N') or
    ...
```

I am failing to parse your weird `AND OR` combinations(that seems incorrect anyway).

If using a `CTE` is not possible you can shorten the following:

```
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 )
```

becomes:

```
right(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)), 1 )
```

and:

```
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1)
```

becomes:

```
left(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)), len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))) -1)
```

and:

```
substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),1,len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))))
```

becomes:

```
ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))
```

Comment: is it possibble to define the CTE after where clause

Comment: but that select statement is huge for which it has many case statements.Also that select query is a subquery of the select statement,,

Comment: No, cte should preced the where clause

Comment: substring(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)),len(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change))),1 )               is this equal to       right(ltrim(rtrim(premium_change)), 1 ) ?

Comment: Yes, both get the last character from the end of the string ignoring spaces.